# Absolute maximum and minimum on the closed disk

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x,y)=exp(x^2-y^2)$ on the set $R^2$ with $x^2+y^2 \leq1$.

I have applied Lagrange Multipliers method, but found that exponent function should be equal to zero if $f$ function has minimum. Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Are you being asked to answer this with Lagrange multipliers, or is that just how you approached this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you solve the *unconstrained* optimization problem on the *interior* of the disk and find that the origin is the only critical point. Of course, it turns out to be a saddle point.

Now consider the Lagrange multiplier problem with the constraint $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2 = 1$. Then $\nabla f = \lambda\nabla g$ if and only if
$$2xe^{x^2-y^2} = \lambda (2x) \quad\text{and}\quad -2ye^{x^2-y^2} = \lambda(2y).$$
Assuming $x,y\ne 0$, we deduce that $\lambda=e^{x^2-y^2} = -\lambda$. As you pointed out, this is impossible. Therefore, we are left with the critical points where $x=0$ and $y=0$ on the unit circle (where one of the equations drops out and there is a solution of the other).
We have $f(\pm 1,0) = e$ and $f(0,\pm 1) = e^{-1}$, so the absolute maximum points are $(\pm 1,0)$ and the absolute minimum points are $(0,\pm 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to polar coordinates

$$
\cases{
x=r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta
}
$$

we get the equivalent problem

$$
\min(\max)e^{r^2\cos(2\theta)}\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ 0\le r\le 1
$$

now along a direction $\theta_0$ as $\{-\theta_0 r\cup\theta_0 r\}$ for $0\le r\le 1$ : for $\theta \ne \pm\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,\ k=0,1,2,\cdots\ $ we have curves in which $\cos(2\theta_0)> 0$ and also curves in which $\cos(2\theta_0) < 0$. For the first curves we have a minimum at $r = 0$ and for the second we have curves with a maximum at $r=0$. Those curves are separated at $\theta = \pm\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi,\ k=0,1,2,\cdots\ $ with lines parallel to the horizontal plane at a height of $z = 1$. The point $z=0$ behaves as a maximum for a curve's class and as a minimum for another curves so this point is a saddle point. The maxima and minima are located at the bordering circle or at $r = 1$ and those points are located at

$$
\cases{
\text{maxima}\to 2\theta = 2k\pi\\
\text{minima}\to 2\theta=(2k+1)\pi
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

A geometrical interpretation of this problem can also be helpful.  Since we are looking for level curves for the function, $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ e^{x^2 \ - \ y^2} \ = \ c \ \ , $ we could work with the curve equation  $ \  x^2 \ - \ y^2  \ = \ \ln c \ \ . $  This is the (square) "horizontal" hyperbola centered on the origin, with its major axis on the $ \ x-$ axis and with asymptotes $ \ y\  = \ \pm x \ $ .

Its vertices then lie at $ \ ( \ \pm \sqrt{\ln c} \ , \ 0 ) \ \ . $  The largest possible value of $ \ \ln c \ $ for which the hyperbola will make contact with the boundary of the disk, $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ 1 \ , $ is thus $  \ \ln c \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ so the **absolute maximum** value of our function occurs for $ \ f(\pm 1 \ , \ 0) \ =  \ e \ \ . $

As we reduce $ \ \ln c \ $ , the vertices close in on the origin, reducing the hyperbola to its "degenerate form" of the two asymptotes.  The two vertices have merged with the center of the hyperbola at $ \ (0 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ for $ \ \ln c \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ c \ = \ 1 \ . $

If we then continue to reduce $ \ \ln c \ $ by making it negative, the curve equation becomes

$$ \  x^2 \ - \ y^2  \ = \ \ln c \ \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \  y^2 \ - \ x^2  \ = \ -| \ \ln c \ |  \ \ , $$

which is a (square) "vertical" hyperbola with the same center and asymptotes, but now with its major axis on the $ \ y-$ axis.  The hyperbola will be just tangent to the boundary for $ \ -| \ \ln c \ | \ = \ 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ln c \ = \ -1 \ \ . $  Hence, the **absolute minimum** value of the function occurs for the vertices  $ \ f(0 \ , \ \pm 1) \ =  \ e^{-1} \ \ . $

In the neighborhood of the origin, as $ \ \ln c \ $ increases from values slightly less than zero to those slightly greater than zero, the two points on the $ \ y-$ axis draw closer together, merge at the origin for $ \ c \ = \ 1 \ $ , and then separate along the $ \ x-$ axis.  Thus, the critical point at the origin behaves as a "saddle point".